# JavaRDD<String> to JavaRDD<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am reading a txt file as a JavaRDD with the following command:

```
JavaRDD<String> vertexRDD = ctx.textFile(pathVertex);
```

Now, I would like to convert this to a JavaRDD because in that txt file I have two columns of Integers and want to add some schema to the rows after splitting the columns.

I tried also this:

```
JavaRDD<Row> rows = vertexRDD.map(line -> line.split("\t"))
```

But is says I cannot assign the map function to an "Object" RDD

1. How can I create a JavaRDD out of a JavaRDD
2. How can I use map to the JavaRDD?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you are using RDD over dataframes? Can you add a few first  lines of your text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a `JavaRDD` out of another is implicit when you apply a transformation such as `map`. Here, the RDD you create is a RDD of arrays of strings (result of `split`).

To get a RDD of rows, just create a Row from the array:

```java
JavaRDD<String> vertexRDD = ctx.textFile("");
JavaRDD<String[]> rddOfArrays = vertexRDD.map(line -> line.split("\t"));
JavaRDD<Row> rddOfRows =rddOfArrays.map(fields -> RowFactory.create(fields));
```

Note that if your goal is then to transform the `JavaRDD<Row>` to a dataframe (`Dataset<Row>`), there is a simpler way. You can change the delimiter option when using `spark.read` to avoid having to use RDDs:

```
Dataset<Row> dataframe = spark.read()
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .csv("your_path/file.csv");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define this two columns as a class's field, and then you can use

```
JavaRDD<Row> rows = rdd.map(new Function<ClassName, Row>() {
            @Override
            public Row call(ClassName target) throws Exception {
                return RowFactory.create(
                        target.getField1(),
                        target.getUsername(),
            }
        });
```

And then create StructField,
finally using

```
StructType struct = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, struct);
```